# Rust converting a struct to key value pair where the field is not none

Tags: rust, struct, rust-cargo, prost

I have a struct generated by prost (protobuf implementation based on proto).

```
pub struct Data {
    #[prost(string, tag="1")]
    pub field1: ::prost::alloc::string::String,
    #[prost(message, optional, tag="2")]
    pub struct_2: ::core::option::Option<Struct2>,
    #[prost(message, optional, tag="3")]
    pub struct_3: ::core::option::Option<Struct3>,
    #[prost(string, tag="4")]
    pub test_param: ::prost::alloc::string::String,
}
```

I am able to decode the protobuf data from the above.

The catch is I receive some fields which are none in the above struct.
only some fields are filled at any given time.

eg:

`Data { field1: "testfield", struct_2: None, struct_3: None, test_param: "test" }`

I want to be able to:

1. select only non-none values from the struct.
2. Iterate over them and put them as a key value pair.

Eg:

```
let keyvalue = Hashmap::new()
for k,v in buffered_data.to_vector().iter() {
  if k.IsSome(){
    keyvalue.insert("k",v)   
  }
}
```

expected output would be something like:

```
keyvalue:
{
"field1":"test_field",
"test_param": "test"
}
```

Comment: Why not put them directly in the map?

Comment: I am receiving the info as  serialized proto bytes and I can decode them to prost structs,

Comment: I mean, why not just do `map.insert("field1", v.field1); if let Some(field2) = v.field2 { map.insert("field2", field2); }` etc.?

Comment: makes sense for short structs, but my struct is really large .i.e it can have upto 100 fields, so an iterator makes sense, is what I am thinking.

Comment: An iterator must have one type, so this is generally impossible (a map too).

Comment: Found this: https://crates.io/crates/structmap. May be helpful.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "put them as a key value pair". Do you want a `Vec<(String, String)>`? Or a `HashMap<String, String>`? Or do you want a json? The tools you would use are very different.